# What's the best way to iterate over results from an APi, and know when it's finished?

Tags: swift

I'm getting data from the FatSecret API. In a nutshell, I have several food IDs I need to get data from, iterating over them to add the calories together. Each one must be a separate call. Since these don't run on the main thread, what's the best way of determining when they are all finished? Currently, I track it with a variable that iterates by one each time a call is finished, but I feel like there may be a better way.

```
    for thisFoodId in foodIds {

    let endpointURL = <URL WITH FOODID>
    guard let url = URL(string: endpointURL) else {
        return
    }
    let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        guard error == nil else {
            return
        }
        guard let responseData = data else {
            return
        }

        do {

            guard let thisData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: []) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
                return
            }

            let calories = thisData["calories"]
            self.totalCalories += calories
            tracker += 1
            if tracker == foodIds.count {
                // RUN COMPLETION CODE
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DispatchGroups`. It will trigger an async callback block when all your requests are completed.

**DispatchGroup:**

> DispatchGroup allows for aggregate synchronization of work. You can
>   use them to submit multiple different work items and track when they
>   all complete, even though they might run on different queues. This
>   behavior can be helpful when progress can’t be made until all of the
>   specified tasks are complete.

In your code, it would like this:

```
// ...

// Create the DispatchGroup:

let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()

for thisFoodId in foodIds {

    // Enter the DispatchGroup:

    dispatchGroup.enter()

    // ...

    let task = session.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: {
        (data, response, error) in

        // ...

        do {

            // ...

            if tracker == foodIds.count {

                // Leave the DispatchGroup

                dispatchGroup.leave()
             }
         }

     })

     // When all your tasks have completed, notify your DispatchGroup to run your work item:

     dispatchGroup.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main, execute: {

         // All your async requests are finished here, do whatever you want :)

     })

}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!